# how to change colour of jquery hint

Tags: php, jquery

how do I change the jquery hint text colour. Currently it is the same colour as the textfield however I would like it to be different!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Shows the title in the text box, and removes it when modifying it
    $('input[title]').each(function (i) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');

        $(this).focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hint');
            }
        });

        $(this).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('hint');
            }
        });
    });

    //Clear input hints on form submit
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('input.hint').val('');
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're looking to style the title attribute you can't.

Answer (score 0):

you change it in the css the same way as in the last thread I just gave you jQuery code replacement for your hints 10 minutes ago

http://jsfiddle.net/jzCeq/2/